# PIC 32 baud rate

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip, pic32

i have a PIC32MX460F512L. I am setting up a UART communication with raspberry Pi 3. And i made also some tests with mi PC Windows serial terminal (Putty, Teraterm etc.). I am having stucking problems, because the raspberry sends and receives only rubbish. Then i tested it with putty on Windows  and i noticed strange things. For example the uart baud rate on the board is set as 9600, and to send and receive data on windows i have to set putty's baud rate to 130 !! Then i had a look to my PCLK settings on pic and it seems like everything is correct since there is an external clk oscillator of 8MHz. I post the code below .

PIC CODE:

```
#define GetSystemClock() (80000000ul) // Hz
#define GetInstructionClock() (GetSystemClock()/1)
#define GetPeripheralClock() (GetInstructionClock()/1) //

long Baud_Rate;





    Baud_Rate = 9600;
    TRISFbits.TRISF8 = 0; // Set UART1TX like output
    TRISFbits.TRISF2 = 1; // Set UART1RX like input
    U1MODE = 0x00008000;
    U1STA = 0x00001400; // RXEN set, TXEN set

    U1BRG = ((USART_Clock_Source)/(Baud_Rate/16))-1;
```

May it be a fault on the external oscillator or maybe is there an error on the baud rate calculation? I cannot understand.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an error:

```
U1BRG = ((USART_Clock_Source)/(Baud_Rate/16))-1;
```

it should be:

```
U1BRG = ((USART_Clock_Source)/(Baud_Rate*16))-1;
```

And this:

```
#define GetSystemClock() (80000000ul) // Hz
```

should be

```
#define GetSystemClock() (8000000ul) // Hz
```

In this calculation is 8 MHz the instruction frequency not the clock frequency. The instruction frequency is half of the clock.

Comment: Thank you @Mike, but it does not change anything in the test.

Comment: Its at least one error. Where did you define `USART_Clock_Source`? What is the value of  `U1BRG` ?

Comment: In this case  USART_Clock_Source = GetPeripheralClock()  and it is defined in the code above.

Comment: And what is the value of `U1BRG`?

Comment: It is 519.83, but is not the same of the baud rate table wich is 51.0

Comment: You are calculating with 80 MHz not 8 MHz

Comment: And you don't need to calculate `Ù1BRGH`at runtime. Just use a constant.

Comment: So is the definition " #define GetSystemClock() (80000000ul) // Hz " wrong? I tryed to chang it in " #define GetSystemClock() (8000000ul) // Hz " but no changes seem to accur. Maybe should I switch the  UART clock source to internal?

Comment: Have a look: https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/60001107H.pdf

Comment: Thank you, as soon as i manage to do some tests i'll let you know if something changes.

Comment: Found the problem, my oscillator is operating at 4 MHz instead of 8. I don't know what happened, maybe it is broken. I set everything to 4 MHz including the brg value,and it works finely. Thanks for your support.